# return multiple values in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, return-value

How can i return multiple values in a jsp java file ?

I want to return error1 and error but thats not working

I have tried this so fare:

```
<%!

String validate(String input) {
        String error = "";
        int receptnr = 0;
        String error1 = "";
        int varenr = 0;
        try {
                    receptnr = Integer.parseInt(input);
                    varenr= Integer.parseInt(input);

        } catch (Exception e) {
                    error = error +"Receptnummeret skal være et tal";
                    error1 = error1 +"Varenummer skal være et tal";
        }
        if (receptnr > 99999999||receptnr<1||varenr > 99999999||varenr<1)
                        error = error + " Receptnummeret skal være mellem 1 og 99999999 år";
                        error1 = error1 + " Varenummeret skal være mellem 1 og 99999999 år";
        return error, error1;


}
%>
```

Later on i want to return more values

Comment: In java a method can only return one object or primitive.

Comment: You can return the values by some delimiter i.e. return error + "," + error1 or you can return multiple values by using Collection API. You can use collection like ArrayList.

Comment: Simple, Use String or Object Array as return type..And whatever the case but never use sciptlets in your JSPs. It is never-ever recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include this in your jsp page

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

type below two lines in jsp page wherever you want to print java variable.
Do not forget to include jstl jar into your project library folder.

```
<c:out value="<%=error%>"/>
<c:out value="<%=error1%>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way returning multiple values with java.

What you can do is change your return type to List and  return a List of Strings in your case.

For a start ,take a look at [List docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Answer (score 0):

you cannot return multiple value like that. You need to use Collection for returning multiple values for e.g,
code sample :

```
List<String> validate(String input) {
List<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
String err="someErr";
list.add(err);

String err2="someErr";
list.add(err2);
return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java7 or above, you can use the

```
void java.lang.Throwable.addSuppressed(Throwable exception)
```

and have an outer exception contain multiple exceptions by throwing the outer exception.

Another way can be to create a class that can contain multiple errors in a List<>, then return an object of this class rather than String.

Answer (score 0):

Here what you can do is You can add this errors in the any collection framework like ArrayList or vector as shown below:

```
        List<String> validate(String input) {
        ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

        list1.add(error);
        list1.add(error1);

    return list1;
}
```

And your written type would be collection.

Answer (score 0):

u may try this:

```
String[] validate(String input) {
    String[] errors = new String[2];
    // ur logic here
    // errors[0] = "some error message";
    // so on
    return errors;
}
```